# translateX to left of viewport

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, velocity.js

Is there a way to translateX to the left side of the viewport? I need to use CSS animation using translateX rather than left.

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGXprL) that approximates what I am trying to do, using the velocity.js plugin. The problem is that I want to animate translateX to the top left  of the viewport, but am not sure how to calculate that..

Here is the relevant javascript where I am setting translateX:

```
.setVelocity(".animate-it", {translateX: '[THIS is where I need help]' }, {duration: 150})
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Myabe set the inital position top left and store it in a class, and do the same for the second state (put it in other class)...And then, via javascript, change the classes that you want applied.